# Replacing foreign keys with data from table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm brand new to ROR and very new to programming.

I'm working on a DB and I want entering information to be easy and user friendly.  In my index pages for my tables any foreign keys are shown as the id.  I would like to learn how to have it display a different column value instead of the id.  For example company_name instead of company_id.

From my very little experience I would guess that the .map method would be used.  I'm not really sure how though. I've already messed around with it for a while with no success.

The lower half of one of my table's index.html looks like this:

```
<% @venture_rounds.each do |venture_round| %>
  <tr>
<td><%= venture_round.raise_amount %></td>
<td><%= venture_round.company_id %></td>
<td><%= venture_round.investor_id %></td>
  </tr>
```

What can I do to have it grab a value from the company and investor table and show it, instead of the id for those tables?

I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Do you have `Company` and `Investor` models defined?  Also please post the relationships you've defined between the three models (if they are all defined): `Company`, `Investor`, `VentureRound`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your VentureRound model has company and investor as defined children

```
class VentureRound < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, :investor 
end
```

Read the information as such

```
venture_round.company.location # or whatever attributes you're seeking
venture_round.investor.name
```